How can reduce the CPU load for this video card?
I have tested two video cards one by one in my Linux box in the first PCI-e x16 slot (next to the CPU).
Old card:
Asus Radeon EAH5570/DI/1GD3(LP)   glmark2 score 1873
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
2958 laci      20   0  588208  46288  29492 S  48.8  0.3   0:20.36 glmark2 

Newer card:
NVIDIA GeForce GT 710/PCIe/SSE2   glmark2 score 1888
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND 
5863 laci      20   0  140784  61280  31448 R 100.0  0.4   1:33.96 glmark2 
1248 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  45.8  0.0   7:33.00 irq/25+ 

GT710 has 3 times larger CPU load than EAH5570 beside about the same score of glmark2 benchmark.
I would prefer to use the GT710 because it has a passive cooling and older has fairly loud fan.
But I would like to know is there a better setting for GT710 card to smaller CPU load keeping
about the same glmark2 benchmark score (1888) ?
The environment is:
Ubuntu 18.04
Mather board is GA-870A GIGABYTE with AMD FX(tm)-6300 (6 core) 3.5GHz with DDR3 RAM 16GByte.
Apart from one video card, the PCI-e,PCI slots are empty.


The GT710 card is 10 years old. Ubuntu 18.04 is over a year past extended support. You have not said what drivers you are using to run the cards. You would be better giving up on this entire system if you have the money. Even current very low spec'd & cheap systems would outrun your setup.
